# dplyr filter for time (but only minutes and seconds)

Tags: r, time, filter, dplyr

I have the following data from Facebook

```
ID               Message          Created_Time
12223            Hello World      2014-10-03T13:16:32+0000
24421            Hello            2014-10-03T13:00:00+0000
34551            Sweet            2014-11-03T13:16:34+0000
12333            Cool             2014-02-26T20:00:00+0000
12231            Really Cool!     2013-03-26T19:00:00+0000
```

My question is now how to filter out the posts that have 00:00+0000 in the time stamp?

I would like to have two data frames. One with the posts that have the 00:00+0000 in the stamp and one with all others.

I tried to do it with grepl, but it did not work. Any help is really appreciated.

Best thanks beforehand.

Comment: What do you mean `grepl` did not work? I tried `df %>% filter(grepl('00:00\\+0000', Created_Time))` and it seems to work fine.

Comment: tried the same thing as @Gopala and it works fine; please share the result of `dput` on your `data.frame`

Answer (score 4):

The `lubridate` library and `dplyr` will make this easier.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

## call your original data frame df and the time column MyTime
df$MyTime<-ymd_hms(df$MyTime)
df2<-filter(df, minute(MyTime)!=0 | sec(MyTime)!=0 )
df3<-fitler(df, minute(MyTime)==0 & sec(MyTime)==0)
```

Edit: added in the `minute` parts as I missed that part at first.